# on centos eclipse Symbol 'XXX' could not be resolved multiple errors coming

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, centos

I have installed eclipse on Centos and installed boost c++ lib.

when i run code it is giving errors like

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Function 'buffer_cast' could not be resolved    TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 112    Semantic Error
Function 'buffer' could not be resolved TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 106    Semantic Error
Function 'connect' could not be resolved    TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 46 Semantic Error
Function 'make_pair' could not be resolved  TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 92 Semantic Error
Function 'make_pair' could not be resolved  TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 93 Semantic Error
Function 'now' could not be resolved    TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 70 Semantic Error
Function 'read_until' could not be resolved TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 111    Semantic Error
Function 'strcmp' could not be resolved TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 74 Semantic Error
Function 'strcmp' could not be resolved TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 74 Semantic Error
Function 'strcmp' could not be resolved TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 79 Semantic Error
Function 'strlen' could not be resolved TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 105    Semantic Error
Function 'write' could not be resolved  TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 106    Semantic Error
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
'   TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 99 Semantic Error
make: *** [TCP_client.o] Error 1    TCP_client          C/C++ Problem
Method 'add_child' could not be resolved    TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 95 Semantic Error
Method 'add_child' could not be resolved    TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 96 Semantic Error
Method 'c_str' could not be resolved    TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 102    Semantic Error
Method 'data' could not be resolved TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 112    Semantic Error
Method 'getline' could not be resolved  TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 52 Semantic Error
Method 'push_back' could not be resolved    TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 92 Semantic Error
Method 'push_back' could not be resolved    TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 93 Semantic Error
Method 'put' could not be resolved  TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 68 Semantic Error
Method 'put' could not be resolved  TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 70 Semantic Error
Method 'put' could not be resolved  TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 76 Semantic Error
Method 'put' could not be resolved  TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 77 Semantic Error
Method 'put' could not be resolved  TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 81 Semantic Error
Method 'put' could not be resolved  TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 82 Semantic Error
Method 'put' could not be resolved  TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 83 Semantic Error
Method 'put' could not be resolved  TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 87 Semantic Error
Method 'put' could not be resolved  TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 88 Semantic Error
Method 'resolve' could not be resolved  TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 43 Semantic Error
Method 'str' could not be resolved  TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 100    Semantic Error
Method 'what' could not be resolved TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 120    Semantic Error
Symbol 'buffer_cast' could not be resolved  TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 112    Semantic Error
Symbol 'cerr' could not be resolved TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 120    Semantic Error
Symbol 'chrono' could not be resolved   TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 23 Semantic Error
Symbol 'cin' could not be resolved  TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 52 Semantic Error
Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 50 Semantic Error
Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 104    Semantic Error
Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 113    Semantic Error
Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 115    Semantic Error
Symbol 'endl' could not be resolved TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 104    Semantic Error
Symbol 'ptree' could not be resolved    TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 18 Semantic Error
Symbol 'read_json' could not be resolved    TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 19 Semantic Error
Symbol 'std' could not be resolved  TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 49 Semantic Error
Symbol 'tcp' could not be resolved  TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 25 Semantic Error
Symbol 'write_json' could not be resolved   TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 20 Semantic Error
Type 'boost::asio::io_service' could not be resolved    TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 39 Semantic Error
Type 'boost::asio::streambuf' could not be resolved TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 110    Semantic Error
Type 'ptree' could not be resolved  TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 61 Semantic Error
Type 'ptree' could not be resolved  TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 62 Semantic Error
Type 'ptree' could not be resolved  TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 64 Semantic Error
Type 'ptree' could not be resolved  TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 65 Semantic Error
Type 'size_t' could not be resolved TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 105    Semantic Error
Type 'size_t' could not be resolved TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 106    Semantic Error
Type 'std::exception' could not be resolved TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 118    Semantic Error
Type 'std::ostringstream' could not be resolved TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 97 Semantic Error
Type 'std::string' could not be resolved    TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 100    Semantic Error
Type 'tcp::resolver::iterator' could not be resolved    TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 43 Semantic Error
Type 'tcp::resolver::query' could not be resolved   TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 42 Semantic Error
Type 'tcp::resolver' could not be resolved  TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 41 Semantic Error
Type 'tcp::socket' could not be resolved    TCP_client.cpp  /TCP_client line 45 Semantic Error
```

Please help in resolving to these issue. I am new to Linux.

i have build same code on VS2008 on windows with BOOST it as working without any issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Environment", add name "LANG" and "LC_ALL" , and all value are "en_US".